# Exit application when all child forms are closed

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, parent-child, exit

In my winform application I have one form that creates other forms during a for loop. This parent form remains hidden is there purely for processing.

I moved the processing code away from the program class because `Application.Run` didn't seem to place nice in a loop as more than one instance would be open.

When the child forms are done with they are closed. What I want to know is whether I can get the application to exit when these forms are closed even though the parent form is still open. I have tried exposing a `List<bool>` on the parent form to store which of the forms have closed but the child forms cannot access the list due to the parent form not having an instance name - it is called by `Application.Run(new FormProcessor(args));`

More generally I guess I am asking is there a way to access properties of the parent form from the child forms.

Comment: You could work with a shared viewmodel, that is initialized from within the parent form, and simply given to the child forms as a constructor parameter or a property. On the other hand, all child forms should have a `FormClosed` event where you could bind yourself to and when a form gets closed, you remove the reference to the form from your list, and once you have an empty list, you call `Application.Exit`

Comment: This all seems like an unnecessary hack for replacing [ApplicationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped with this. I have come up with an answer that works for me. I've added an event handler on the back of form closed. The `origList` variable stores the original data for `formList` otherwise the `foreach` will proceed to the next entry of the list which it may have removed.

```
for ( int i =0; i < formList.Count; i++)
        {
                string formName = formList[i];

                    Form1 frm = (new Form1(formName...);
                    frm.Show();
                    string contextName= formName;
                    frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler((sender, e) => FrmClosed_Event(sender, e, contextName));                                     
        }

       public void FrmClosed_Event(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e, string name)
        {
            foreach(string thisForm in origList)
            {
                if (thisForm == name)
                { formList.Remove(thisForm); }
            }
            if (formList.Count == 0)
            { Application.Exit(); }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Inject a reference to the parent form in the constructor of each child form, thus allowing access to it.

Or when each child form is created add a reference to a list in the parent form then run a background task to wait for all the child forms to close.  You could do this by subscribing to the form closed event on each of the child forms and waiting for these to fire

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of what I have tried to show in the comments would be the following.

You create an extra class that handles the registration to the FormClosed event as for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace wfAutoClose {
  public class FormSubscriber : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly IList<Form> _forms = new ObservableCollection<Form>();
    public IList<Form> Forms {
      get {
        return _forms;
      }
    }

    public int FormCount {
      get {
        return _forms.Count;
      }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
      var localEvent = PropertyChanged;
      if (localEvent != null) {
        localEvent.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName: propertyName ) );
      }
    }

    private void OnChildFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
      Forms.Remove( sender as Form );
    }

    private void SubscribeToFormClosedEvent(Form childForm) {
      childForm.FormClosed += OnChildFormClosed;
    }

    private void UnsubscribeFromFormClosedEvent(Form childForm) {
      childForm.FormClosed -= OnChildFormClosed;
    }

    private void OnChildFormCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
      if (e.OldItems != null) {
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems) {
          UnsubscribeFromFormClosedEvent( item as Form );
        }
      }
      if (e.NewItems != null) {
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems) {
          SubscribeToFormClosedEvent( item as Form );
        }
      }
      RaisePropertyChanged( "FormCount" );
    }

    public void Dispose() {
      ( Forms as INotifyCollectionChanged ).CollectionChanged -= OnChildFormCollectionChanged;
    }

    public FormSubscriber() {
      ( Forms as INotifyCollectionChanged ).CollectionChanged += OnChildFormCollectionChanged;
    }
  }
}
```

this one can then be used inside your parent form, where you simply add the forms in your loop, and your parent form can register itself to the INotifyPropertyChanged event of the FormSubscriber. When there are no more forms available, it will show `FormCount == 0` where this is the place you will exit from your application (by either calling `Application.Exit()` or `this.Close()`)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace wfAutoClose {
  public partial class Form1: Form {
    FormSubscriber formSubscriber = new FormSubscriber();

    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      formSubscriber.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {
      if (formSubscriber.FormCount == 0) {
        Application.Exit();
      }
    }

    private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
      for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        Form form = new Form2() { Text = "Dynamic Form " + i };
        form.Show();
        formSubscriber.Forms.Add( form );
      }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed( object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e ) {
      formSubscriber.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, in my example they are just basic windows, and I do not care about any threading or other GUI specifics, but it should show you the basics of what you could do with the event registration and the usage of the `ObservableCollection<T>` (see FormSubscriber)

Comment: Thanks @icepickle, I have gone for a similar approach.

`Form1 frm = new Form1(formname...);


frm.Show();


frm.FormClosed += new formClosedEventHandler((sender, e) => FormClosed_Event(sender, e, formname));`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest of all would be to keep information about opened/closed forms in some other global class like:

```
public static class Helper
{
   public static List<int> ChildFormsOpened { get; private set; }

   static Helper()
   {
       ChildFormsOpened = new List<int>();   
   }
}
```

You can simply add form hashcode when you open it. You can do this in ctor or load event handler of your child form when it is opened :

```
Helper.ChildFormsOpened.Add(this.GetHashCode());
```

So at some point in your code you can remove the form that is closing from collection and check if all other forms are closed as well. If they are, so you can close your application by invoking `Application.Exit()` method:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
       Helper.ChildFormsOpened.Remove(this.GetHashCode());
       if(Helper.ChildFormsOpened.Count < 1) Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: which component needs to check  if the ChildFormOpened list is 0? The one who closes it, or the parent, who has in your sample, no idea that something got closed?

Comment: Well, it depends on project needs where OP is going to make this check, from which class. But i guess to check it in child`FormClosing` event handler would be the simplest choice. When each child form is about to close it makes this check and if necessary (all forms are closed) - closes the application

Answer (score 1):

Use ApplicationContext and subscribe to the FormClosed() event of all the child forms.  Check the Application.OpenForms collection and Exit() when appropriate...

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyContext());
    }

}

public class MyContext : ApplicationContext
{

    public MyContext()
    {
        // Open your Forms...
        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Form frm = new Form();
            frm.Text = "Form #" + i.ToString();
            frm.FormClosed += Frm_FormClosed;
            frm.Show(); 
        }
    }

    private void Frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

}
```